# Reddit-like hot page backend architecture

Tags: architecture, reddit

Im trying to make the backend design of how reddit computes and serves it hot pages. I also use a "hot" rating to order posts on my site. I have some issues with it that I'm trying to overcome. These are some of the ways I think it may make sense to design:

**Computing hot values:** at the moment I'm computing the value and storing it in the db along with the vote itself everytime someone upvotes a post or anytime someone loads the post. This is probably not great. I'm thinking of simply updating the hot value of all post via a cron job every 5 minutes for example and only for posts that are newer than 2 months for example. This design should work function for thousands and thousands of posts, some I'm not sure if thats the best solution but I did read that reddit at least at the beginning did use cron jobs to do this.

**Querying posts**: This is the part im more worried about at this very moment. Right now the problem is that if I scroll (more posts are loaded at the bottom of the page) I may see duplicate posts due to posts rising and falling in the hot value. Right now every time new posts are loaded a db query is made to retrieve the posts. I'm thinking it will be making a lot of sense to use memcached and cache the queries for posts (this will need to apply to a lot of pages) but im not sure if that will solve my problem entirely. Ideally, I find a solution which basically "snapshots" (caches?) the db and loads from that version of the table in the db until a new page is loaded.

This is a problem that has been plaguing me for ages and I'm trying to find a proper solution about how to best and most efficiently compute the hot rating values and get the posts by order of the hot rating without the values changing (to avoid duplicates and possibly missing posts) as I scroll down the page and load new sets of posts, all while keeping the process nice and efficient. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't worry that much about duplicate posts. Most sites (including reddit) have that problem.

I don't think there is a solution that scales well. Most sites value performance and scalability over consistency. That's why nosql is getting more popular for things like these. They don't guarantee consistency (or only eventual consistency), but give better performance and horizontal scalability in return.

If you really want to solve it, I'd look at the client-side. From your description I understand that you will have an 'infinite scroll' kind of site. You could let the client 'remember' what posts are already shown. If the server sends it more posts (when scrolling down), the client could filter out the ones it's already showing above, e.g. by keeping a list of post id's.

Comment: I actually already store the post that the user has seen in as a session variable and this does work reasonably well, just the way it works it can be flawed in certain instances particularly in mobile when for whatever reason sometimes the variable gets emptied somewhere in the middle. Maybe working with that and tweaking it is the best way. Also any thoughts on computing the hot values? Would doing it in a cronjob and maybe saving those values in memcached be better?

Comment: For computing the hot values, I'd go with the cron approach, especially since time is probably an important aspect of the 'hotness' calculation. It's also the most consistent and easiest to tweak. If the calculation affects performance, you can e.g. temporarily just lower the frequency of the calculations.

Comment: When you store the shown posts as a session variable, that's still server-side. What I meant was to let the client-side decide which posts to actually add. It can e.g. look in its DOM to verify which posts are already shown.
I'm not really sure what to do if the user scrolls down very far or takes a long time, so that most of the replies from the server will already have been shown. In that case all replies from the server can already have been shown, while the current hottest ones are not returned any more. Perhaps the client could start requesting the hottest posts again in that situation?

Comment: Oh I see what youre saying. I was thinking about something like that too. I just had trouble thinking about how to implement it. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> Right now the problem is that if I scroll (more posts are loaded at the bottom of the page) I may see duplicate posts due to posts rising and falling in the hot value.

This is a long-standing problem in reddit.  There's no easy solution, but you can use client-side approaches to hide posts that are already present on the current page.

> Computing hot values: at the moment I'm computing the value and storing it in the db along with the vote itself everytime someone upvotes a post or anytime someone loads the post. This is probably not great.

[reddit's hot sort](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/lib/db/_sorts.pyx#L44-L58) doesn't take into account number of views, so there's no need for them to update on every view of a thread.  However, they do update sort values on every vote, either up, down, or un-vote.  As long as you do this in a separate queue and have enough queue processors, it's a reasonably scalable approach.

If you do want to include page views in your sort calculation, I might approach it with a buffered approach similar to how [StatsD](https://github.com/etsy/statsd) handles metrics: on every page load, send a ping to some service that can write these values to memory very quickly, and periodically that service flushes those values, all together, to more permanent storage.  You could probably do this directly with [pixel ping](https://documentcloud.github.io/pixel-ping/) by just writing the handler that it flushes to.